# Stream HE-AACv2 Audio with Android Media Player

Tags: android, audio, streaming, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to stream live audio through Android's media player. I have it working for mp3 and other formats, but the audio I need to stream is HE-AACv2. Is there any way I can stream this format or maybe convert this format into a supported format, e.g. mp3?

Specifically, the audio I'm trying to stream can be found here: http://ice7.securenetsystems.net/KLIQ

Comment: Did the stream change?
I used this URL in a MediaPlayer object (using `MediaPlayer.setDataSource(String path)` and it worked for me.
But I'm having trouble getting a certain HE-AACv2 stream to work.